# openbox: change brightness or contrast or saturation only for given window / application

Tags: display, xrandr, openbox

I can adjust brightness or gamma of my whole screen with `xrandr`.

But is it possible to only change these settings for given window in `openbox?

For instance, if my browser is too bright and I want to reduce the colors, without affecting other applications?

## EDIT:

I am using `xrandr` as an example here. I don't require the solution to use `xrandr`. If there is some other tool that can do that, that would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xrandr` is configuration utility of RandR (Resize and Rotate), part of X.org Server.

Compiz config [has a setting for this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062510/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-brightness-for-only-a-single-window) but I'm not aware of any similar utility for OpenBox, and don't find any direct method to affect window brightness in [OpenBox documentation](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Contents) either. As per the FAQ you can get [true 32-bit transparency](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:FAQ#How_do_I_get_true_32-bit_transparent_windows.3F) on any window using `xcompmgr` or `transset`, which could be a workaround.

To have a native brightness support for application windows you need a different window manager like [Compiz](http://www.compiz.org/).

Comment: thanks. I don't insist on using `xrandr`. Is there some other tool that could do that?

Comment: No indeed you didn't. I really need to finish my morning coffee first... There might be a workaround, I updated the answer.